# Read coulmn value(except header) backwards and print everything till delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have `xlsx` file which contains several columns.  I want using pandas to read column value(except header) backwards and print everything till delimiter `\`

Input - winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient_4Operational.evtx

Output - Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient_4Operational.evtx

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link under your question, to update it with more info. Putting codes, test data in the comments makes them unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

pd.read_excel can help you, please read:

1. [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel)